# Finding an orthogonal basis w/ inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e3Ol.png)

I am having trouble solving this problem. I can't find a solution and am doubting if I am right. Im thinking I let q = p2 - proj[p0, p1]p2, since that would be orthogonal to both p1 and p0. So I got q = t^2-5 and thus [p0,p1, q] should be the orthogonal basis spanned by [p0, p1, p2]. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It is also in your best interest to show the details of your work. You might have the right idea but are making some simple error along the way that someone could point out to you. See [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heere $\mathbb{P}_3$ denotes the vector space of all the real polynomials of degree not exceding $3$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers.

Let $W$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{P}_3$ spanned by the polynomials $p_0(t) = 1$, $p_1(t) = t$, and $p_2(t) = t^2$. Then $W$ is the subspace of all the real polynomials of degree at most $2$.

For any polynomials $p, q \in \mathbb{P}_3$, we define
$$
\langle p, q \rangle \colon= p(-3) q(-3) + p(-1)q(-1) + p(1)q(1) + p(3) q(3).
$$
And it can be easily shown that this formula indeed defines an inner product on $\mathbb{P}_3$.

We apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process on the ordered set $\left( p_0, p_1, p_2 \right)$ to obtain the ordered set $\left( e_0, e_1, e_2 \right)$ such that the set 
$\left( e_0, e_1, e_2 \right)$ is orthonormal and we also obtain
$$
\mbox{ span } \left\{ p_0 \right\} = \mbox{ span } \left\{ e_0 \right\},
$$
$$
\mbox{ span } \left\{ p_0, p_1 \right\} = \mbox{ span } \left\{ e_0, e_1 \right\},
$$
and 
$$
\mbox{ span } \left\{ p_0, p_1, p_2 \right\} = \mbox{ span } \left\{ e_0, e_1, p_2 \right\}.
$$

Now we note that
$$
\left\langle p_0, p_0 \right\rangle = \left(p_0(-3) \right)^2 + \left(p_0(-1) \right)^2 + \left(p_0(1) \right)^2 + \left(p_0(3) \right)^2 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4, 
$$
and so
$$
\left\lVert p_0 \right\rVert = \sqrt{ \left\langle p_0, p_0 \right\rangle  } = 2.
$$
Let us put
$$
e_0 \colon= \frac{1}{ \left\lVert p_0 \right\rVert } p_0. 
$$
Then $e_0$ is a "unit vector" in $\mathbb{P}_3$, and the formula for $e_0$ is given by
$$
e_0 (t) = \frac{1}{2}. \tag{Definition 0} 
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle p_1, e_0 \right\rangle &= p_1(-3) e_0(-3) + p_1(-1) e_0(-1) + p_1(1) e_0(1) + p_1(3) e_0(3) \\
&= (-3) \frac12 + (-1) \frac12 + (1) \frac12 + (3) \frac12 \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
$$
and so
$$
p_1^\prime \colon= p_1 - \left\langle p_1, e_0 \right\rangle e_0 = p_1.
$$
Now we find that
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle p_1^\prime, p_1^\prime \right\rangle &= \left\langle p_1, p_1 \right\rangle \\
&=  \left( p_1(-3) \right)^2 + \left( p_1(-1) \right)^2 + \left( p_1(1) \right)^2 + \left( p_1(3) \right)^2 = (-3)^2 + (-1)^2 + (1)^2 + (3)^2 \\
&= 20,
\end{align}
$$
and thus
$$
\left\lVert p_1^\prime \right\rVert = \sqrt{ \left\langle p_1^\prime, p_1^\prime \right\rangle } = \sqrt{ 20 } = 2 \sqrt{5}.
$$
Let us now put
$$
e_1 \colon= \frac{1}{ \left\lVert p_1^\prime \right\rVert  } p_1^\prime = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 \sqrt{5} } p_1
$$
Then $e_1$ is also a unit vector in $\mathbb{P}_3$ and such that 
$$ \left\langle e_0, e_1 \right\rangle = 0; $$
moreover $e_1$ is given by the formula
$$
e_1(t) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{5} } t. \tag{Definition 1} 
$$

Next we find
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle p_2, e_0 \right\rangle &= p_1(-3) e_0(-3) + p_1(-1) e_0(-1) + p_1(1) e_0(1) + p_1(3) e_0(3) \\
&= (-3)^2 \frac12 + (-1)^2 \frac12 + (1)^2 \frac12 + (3)^2 \frac12 \\
&= 10,
\end{align}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle p_2, e_1 \right\rangle &= p_2(-3) e_1(-3) + p_2(-1) e_1(-1) + p_2(1) e_1(1) + p_2(3) e_1(3) \\
&= (-3)^2 \frac1{2\sqrt{5}}(-3)  + (-1)^2 \frac1{2\sqrt{5}} (-1) + (1)^2 \frac1{2\sqrt{5}}(1) + (3)^2 \frac1{2\sqrt{5}}(3) \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
$$
and then
$$
p_2^\prime \colon= p_2 - \left\langle p_2, e_0 \right\rangle e_0 - \left\langle p_2, e_1 \right\rangle e_1 = p_2 - 10 e_0 - 0 e_1 = p_2 - 10 e_0,
$$
and as 
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle p_2^\prime, p_2^\prime \right\rangle &= \left( p_2^\prime(-3) \right)^2 +  \left( p_2^\prime(-1) \right)^2 +  \left( p_2^\prime(1) \right)^2 +  \left( p_2^\prime(3) \right)^2 \\
&= \left( (-3)^2 - 10 \times \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + \left( (-1)^2 - 10 \times \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + \left( (1)^2 - 10 \times \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + \left( (3)^2 - 10 \times \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \\
&= 64,
\end{align}
$$
and thus
$$
\left\lVert p_2^\prime \right\rVert = \sqrt{ \left\langle p_2^\prime, p_2^\prime \right\rangle  } = 8.
$$
Let us now put
$$
e_2 \colon= \frac1{ \left\lVert p_2^\prime \right\rVert   } p_2^\prime = \frac18 p_2^\prime = \frac18 \left( p_2 - 10 e_0 \right).
$$
This $e_2$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{P}_3$ and is orthogonal to both $e_0$ and $e_1$; moreover $e_2$ is given by the formula
$$
e_2(t) = \frac18 \left( t^2 - 5 \right) = \frac{1}{8} t^2 - \frac58. \tag{Definition 2}
$$

The vectors $e_0$, $e_1$, and $e_2$ given by the formulas in (Definition 0), (Definition 1), and (Definition 2), respectively, are the vectors in our desired orthonormal basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{P}_3$ spanned by the vectors $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Gram-Schmidt process to get your basis. Fortunately, $p_0$ and $p_1$ are orthogonal, and so are $p_1$ and $p_2$; this simplifies the computations. If you apply this process to $\{p_0,p_1,p_2\}$, you will get an orthogonal basis (which is even orthonormal) is$$\left\{\frac12,\frac t{2\sqrt5},\frac18(t^2-5)\right\}.$$A simpler answer (orthogonal but not orthonormal) is $\{1,t,t^2-5\}$.